# AdminBro bundles "No such file or directory" error

Tags: node.js, nginx, admin-bro

I'm just trying to run AdminBro on my docker container with NodeJS and Nginx and I am getting the following errors from the nginx error log:

```
2021/06/05 07:34:28 [error] 13187#13187: *24 open() "/home/aguero/lasfar/website/admin/frontend/assets/global.bundle.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /admin/frontend/assets/global.bundle.js HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/admin"
2021/06/05 07:34:28 [error] 13187#13187: *24 open() "/home/aguero/lasfar/website/admin/frontend/assets/app.bundle.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /admin/frontend/assets/app.bundle.js HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/admin"
2021/06/05 07:34:28 [error] 13187#13187: *26 open() "/home/aguero/lasfar/website/admin/frontend/assets/design-system.bundle.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /admin/frontend/assets/design-system.bundle.js HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/admin"
2021/06/05 07:34:28 [error] 13187#13187: *26 open() "/home/aguero/lasfar/website/admin/frontend/assets/components.bundle.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /admin/frontend/assets/components.bundle.js HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/admin"
```

The web page does not show any error, but is blank.

admin.js:

```
// ============================================
// Admin Bro
const AdminBro = require('admin-bro')
const AdminBroExpress = require('@admin-bro/express')

const adminBro = new AdminBro({
  databases: [],
  rootPath: '/admin',
})
adminBro.watch()

const router = AdminBroExpress.buildRouter(adminBro)

// ============================================
// Server
const express = require("express");
const server = express();

server
  .use(adminBro.options.rootPath, router)
  .listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started"));
```

admin.js is under /home/aguero/lasfar/website/nodejs

nginx.conf:

```
user  aguero;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;

        location /admin {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    } 
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
}
```

There are more locations on the nginx.conf file, but they are in totally different paths so I removed them for simplicity.
I installed NodeJS with the setup_16.x script and APT. The packages were installed with:

```
npm install tslib
npm i admin-bro @admin-bro/express express express-formidable
```

I am mapping the port 80 from the container to the host's 8080 port.
Any idea why these errors are appearing? I can provide more info, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To me this forward slash (/) in the proxy_pass in ngnix.config resulted in the bug. Assuming you have your express app running on port 8000 and adminBro/adminJs is accessible by 8000/admin

```
location ^~ /admin/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/admin/;
}
```